# What is quantum molecular movement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vibrations, molecules

Q: What is quantum molecular movement? And what are some examples of quantum molecular movement?

I’ve been studying a wide arrange of things but one of the top things I don’t understand is quantum molecular movement. I’ve been told about it but I don’t really understand and know the concept very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum molecular movement generally refers to the vibration and rotation of molecules.

Molecules can vibrate either because interatomic distances oscillate or because a bond bends or twists. These vibrations are similar to the states of a quantum harmonic oscillator, so these vibrational energies are quantized.

Molecules can also rotate as a whole in space. Their angular momentum and thus their rotational energy is quantized.